# javascript: How to get the input field's intermediate state?

Tags: javascript

I use a InputMethod such as Chinese Sougou Pinyin input method program.

When user inputs some content, the input field's value changed, but that value is a intermediate state, like the following image, **with the underline**. When user types a blank space, the content change immediately.

I want to know: how to get / check this state by javascript?

[[the image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQJD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQJD.png)

Comment: I can get the input value, but how to check whether in the intermediate state with underline?

Comment: only in chrome has this bug

Answer (score 0):

How about listening key press and responding when space key (or other trigger keys) is down before getting the value out. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/b0eohhnm/

```
$('#text').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        console.log($('#text').val())
    }
})
```